# get keyboard events in node-js background service/app

Tags: node.js

Most solutions for keyboard rely on std-in or a foreground service. How would one get events in a node-js based app running in background?

I could only find this here: [nodejs keydown/keyup events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317504/nodejs-keydown-keyup-events) but it requires SDL bindings.

Any ideas? For now I can only think of a native solution.

ps: I am aware this possibly needs different implementations on Windows/Linux/Mac. And this is part of an dedicated automation system, please ignore security concerns.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you want to do that? Sniffing keypresses from a background service is not what I would want a third party program doing on my machine.

Comment: its part of an automation system which has to respond to certain 'global' keystrokes by the users. Its not really aiming at the usual desktop computers

Comment: are you sure you want post this as 'answer' ? others would downvote this

Comment: I have a new user profile so I can't comment right now. Obviously on my own answers I can. It's not an answer.. that't correct. But a real answer is public and is potentially a sniffing solution. So I stand by my answer-which-should-be-a-comment.

Comment: as you wish, your concerns are usually not requested in an answer, just saying.